# gojs access target object inside binding

Tags: javascript, gojs

Trying to make some user permissions inside goJS graph. Is there any way to access target object inside binding function. I have graph where my nodes and links have "feAttr" (can be true or false), and I want to access that attribute inside binding function, but there are no examples how to do that.

This is example of my node template and I want to access its attributes inside:

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
          $(go.Node, "Auto",
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
              {
                parameter1: 20,  // the corner has a large radius
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 201, 0)", 1: "rgb(254, 162, 0)" }),
                stroke: null,
                portId: "",  // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
                fromLinkable: true, fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                toLinkable: true, toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                cursor: "pointer"
              }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              {
                font: "bold 11pt helvetica, bold arial, sans-serif",
                editable: true  // editing the text automatically updates the model data
                //textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons, // defined in textEditorRadioButtons.js
                // this specific TextBlock has its own choices:
              },
          new go.Binding("editable", "text", function(t) { 
            console.log("inside node binding editable!");

            console.log("NEED TO ACCESS TARGET OBJECT, BUT HOW ???");

            return (targetObject.data.feAttr && t === "?"); 

          }),
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a second argument in the binding conversion function. Please read the "Advanced Conversions" section of https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Binding.html.

For example:

```
new go.Binding("editable", "text", function(t, textblock) {
  return textblock.part.data.feAttr && t === "?";
})
```

Or you can just refer to the whole bound data object:

For example:

```
new go.Binding("editable", "", function(data) {
  return data.feAttr && data.text === "?";
})
```

But this kind of Binding will be evaluated much more often than one with a property name as the data source.

Comment: The relevant information should be shared here, in your answer. Link-only answers are discouraged.